# TestCafe setNativeDialogHandler for Location access

Tags: geolocation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I can't get the function setNativeDialogHandler to close chrome's "Know Your Location" dialog. Here's how I call it:

```
await t
  .typeText(this.rallyPostUpdateField, message, { paste: true, replace: true })
  .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
  .click(this.rallyPostUpdateSubmitButton);
```

The user enters some text into an input, then when clicking a submit button, the "Know your location" pop-up shows up.  I even tried calling `setNativeDialogHandler` after the click:

```
await t
  .typeText(this.rallyPostUpdateField, message, { paste: true, replace: true })
  .click(this.rallyPostUpdateSubmitButton)
  .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
```

No luck.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, TestCafe doesn't allow you to handle the 'Know your location' dialog out of the box.

Track this [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3224) to know when this feature will be implemented.

In the meantime, you can consider using a workaround from https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1991#issuecomment-350284141.

Comment: UPD: There is an example in the TestCafe docs on how to mock the Geolocation API in test code. Check the following section to learn more: [Browser API Mocks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/examples/#browser-api-mocks).